# smartctl says test result PASSED but Extended offline tested complete immidiately with read failure (in linux)

Tags: linux, smartctl

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-18-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD40NDZW-11MR8S1
Serial Number:    WD-WX42D113H9XX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 269d2311c
Firmware Version: 02.01A02
User Capacity:    4,000,753,475,584 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Aug 30 23:55:22 2022 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (13200) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 161) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   108   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       17
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4383
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       225
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   197   197   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       2920
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       4413
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   194   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       19449
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   101   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       51
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       347
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       44
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      4413         357112136
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      4413         357112136
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      4412         357112136
```

UPDATE  (what does this suppose means?)
Note it is external usb HDD connected to powered usb HUB)

```
sudo smartctl -t short -C /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-18-generic] (local build)

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in captive mode".
Command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in captive mode" failed: Connection timed out

 sudo smartctl -t long -C /dev/sdc
 smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-18-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in captive mode".
Command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in captive mode" failed: Connection timed out
```

[here](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/303) explains why captive mode dont work

Comment: Don't expect that to be the reason here, but I saw flukes from "powered" (well, until you actually draw power) USB hubs or long cables before, might want to avoid that when testing spinny things behind SATA adapters.

Comment: Its external usb hub, connected to usb of PC (with external cable of power). I have read that smartctl tests cannot execute on usb connection. But this disk is external usb!!! Even i run short/long tests without captivity, they finished less than 5 secs reporting "Completed: read failure " which of course i think it is false. badblocks on 25% reported none. However, i am somehow anxious cause other similar (all passport HDD and near-buy dates), dont report on statistics Raw_Read_Error_Rate (=0 or 1), Reallocated_EventCount (=0), or Current_Pending_Sector (=0). So what to expect? to replace it?